# Google pagerank change after installing SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, pagerank

I just installed a new SSL certificate on one of my sites, also I've redirected the entire traffic to use https instead of http. What will happen with my current Google page rank ? It will be transferred to the "new" https version or I will have a split page rank one for the http and one for the https version ?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a permanent redirection 301, google will keep the rank, but if your redirecting temporarily, then it will split them. so make sure you're using 301 redirection.

more info [here](http://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection).

Comment: Thanks. I've used "Redirect permanent / https://...." from one of the Apache config files. Will this automatically include 301 or do I need to do something else ?

Comment: I guess it does. I've checked from the Webmaster's tools and when I fetch as Google I see an: "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" on the first line. I've accepted your answer (can't upvote you because I don't have 15 points).